# Pip install modules not installing

Tags: python, module

I imported the module `requests` within my project using:

```
pip install requests
```

Apparently the module implementation did not work.

This is the error:

```
File "scraping.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
```

Comment: From where are you running your python script? Command Line? Any IDE?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Run pip install requests and the make sure run python3 file.py

Comment: try running pip3 install requirements and make sure your pip version is up to date @user14102083

Answer (score 1):

### Error explanation

This error basically says it can't find the `requests` module, which is a third party module for handling http requests. There are a few issues that could cause this, but likely it just didn't install properly when you tried to `pip install requests`

### Solution

Depending on your OS you can call pip from your python installation directly through:

#### Windows

`python -m pip install requests`

#### MacOS/Linux

`sudo python3 -m pip install requests`

Comment: This might also not answer his question.

Comment: @YannickFunk with the amount of info given I think this is most likely the issue. I will wait for OP to post any additional details and go from there with the solution. This is usually caused because of a PATH error, and the solution I posted just band-aids that PATH error.

Comment: There might also be multiple Python installations or virtual environments conflicting with each other

Comment: @YannickFunk could be, in that case the solution entirely depends on the VE management tool used. I would still suggest this solution until the author mentions that they're using a VE since the majority of people don't use virtual environments with python.

Comment: yes we can adapt the answer if he clarifies his problem

Answer (score 0):

`pip show <package name>`

will give you information about a specific package.

Here is a link with more info on pip show:

[more info on pip show from the offical pip documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_show/)

you can also do:

`pip list`

in the command line to get a list of all the packages pip has installed.

Note: in WSL(Windows Subsystem for Linux) you may need to use `pip.exe list` and
`pip.exe show` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a while ago where I installed the module with pip and got the same error.
I used Pycharm IDE and had to go into settings -> project settings -> project interpreter and installed the module from there, which made it work. Might be similar in your IDE.